# Pyecharts : different colours according to category in a bar plot

Tags: python, plot, echarts

I have this code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pyecharts.charts import Bar
from pyecharts import options as opts
from pyecharts.globals import ThemeType

my_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'colA' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'colB' : ['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
    'val' : [10, 12, 5, 5, 8, 2, 15],
})

type_colors = {
            'A': 'green',
            'B': 'yellow',
            'C': 'brown'
        }

bar = Bar(init_opts=opts.InitOpts(theme=ThemeType.LIGHT))
bar.add_xaxis(my_df.colB.tolist())
bar.add_yaxis('My Data', my_df.val.astype(int).tolist())
bar.reversal_axis()
bar.render_notebook()
```

I'd like the bars to take the colours defined in type_colors according to the category indicated in colA

I know it's possible in echarts :

```
series: [
    {
      data: [
        120,
        {
          value: 200,
          itemStyle: {
            color: '#a90000'
          }
        },
        150,
        80,
        70,
        110,
        130
      ],
      type: 'bar'
    }
  ]
```

but i don't know how to do it in pyecharts